# ggplot2: Empty white column in a geom_bin2d plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot some data of the kind:

```
example <- data.frame(
  m_A=sample(c(0.000000e+00, 2.777778e-08, 5.555556e-08, 8.333333e-08, 1.111111e-07, 1.388889e-07, 1.666667e-07, 1.944444e-07, 2.222222e-07, 2.500000e-07), 1000, replace=T), 
  Ne_A=sample(c(100000.0, 188888.9, 277777.8, 366666.7, 455555.6, 544444.4, 633333.3, 722222.2,811111.1, 900000.0), 1000, replace=T))
```

As a 2D histogram:

```
example %>% ggplot(aes(x=Ne_A, y=m_A)) +
  geom_bin2d(bins = 10) +
  theme_bw()
```

The result has an empty white column:

[image]

This is annoying. Would anybody be able to suggest how to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After experimenting with different numbers of bins, it appears that `geom_bin2d(bins = n)` creates `n` vertical bins and `n+1` horizontal bins. This unexpected, and counter to the help page for the function. It could be a bug. You get that blank column because no data are in that bin. As a quick fix, you can specify the number of bins as a 2-element vector, where the first element is the number of x bins, and the second element is the number of y bins. The following gets you what you want, but it is not the expected behavior of the function.

```
example %>% ggplot(aes(x=Ne_A, y=m_A)) +
  geom_bin2d(bins = c(9,10)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]